# why blogs are not showing as a list?

Tags: reactjs

i am a beginner in React.js. i am trying to show blogs as a list array but it's not showing. code as followed:

```
const Posts=props=>{
    return(
        <div className="Title">
            <div className="Content">

                <img className="Image"
                src={props.author.imageUrl}
                alt={props.author.Text}
                />
                <div className="User">
                {props.author.Text}

                </div>
            </div>
        <div className="Post-Title">
        {props.Title}
        </div>
        <div className="Post-Content">
        {props.Content}
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}
const posts =[{
    Title: 'Just A Title',
    Content: 'This is the first post in react.',
    author:{
        Text:'Just an image',
        imageUrl:'https://placekitten.com/g/64/64'
    }
},
{
    Title: 'Just A Title',
    Content: 'This is the first post in react.',
    author:{
        Text:'Just an image',
        imageUrl:'https://placekitten.com/g/64/64'
    }}
]

const blog=props=>{
    return(
        <Posts
            Title={posts.Title}
            Content={posts.Content}
            author={posts.author}
            />
    )

}
const postList=props=>{
    const plists=props.blog.map((p,i)=>{
        return(
            <React.Fragment key={i}>
        {p.Title}
        {p.Content}
        {p.author}
        <hr/>
        </React.Fragment>

        )
    })
return <div>{plists}</div>
}
class Post extends Component {

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <postList blog={blog}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

problem is when i excute **npm start** there is no error but in localhost there is nothing. My main goal is to make the post with createPost.js. createPost.js is working showing the input boxes. that's why i put manual post for testing

Answer (score 0):

I removed some code because I don't what it's purpose is but the following will work.

```js
const Post = ({ post }) => {
  return (
    <div className="Title">
      <div className="Content">
        <img
          className="Image"
          src={post.author.imageUrl}
          alt={post.author.Text}
        />
        <div className="User">{post.author.Text}</div>
      </div>
      <div className="Post-Title">{post.Title}</div>
      <div className="Post-Content">{post.Content}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
const Posts = ({ posts }) => {
  return posts.map((post, i) => (
    <Post post={post} key={i} />
  ));
};

const Blog = ({ posts }) => {
  return <Posts posts={posts} />;
};

const App = () => (
  <Blog
    posts={[
      {
        Title: 'Just A Title',
        Content: 'This is the first post in react.',
        author: {
          Text: 'Just an image',
          imageUrl: 'https://placekitten.com/g/64/64',
        },
      },
      {
        Title: 'Just A Title',
        Content: 'This is the first post in react.',
        author: {
          Text: 'Just an image',
          imageUrl: 'https://placekitten.com/g/64/64',
        },
      },
    ]}
  />
);



//render app
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: My target is to use map to make an array list.... after one post there will be horizontal line and another post will start. I want to do this so that later after using state in createpost, the recent post will be added in the first row.

Comment: @rony01 You do `<postList blog={blog}/>` in postList you do `props.blog.map` but `blog` is not an array: `const blog=props=>{`. That should cause an error but I don't think you are rendering anything. Did you create a project with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)?

Comment: Of course yes. This is just the file of Post.js and last line was export default Post. I have another CreatePost.js and everything was rendered in App.js By <post> and <CreatePost>. CreatePost.js is working because I can the see the title and content textarea box. My way of expression might be wrong but the thing I want to do the iteration through map so that in later time I can use state or hook For further add remove or edit option. To do this I am following taniarascia’s table example and reactjs.org official documentation to learn it from the very beginning. hope you understand my problem.